# Map api route to mvc route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, routes

I want my FilesController to be accesible from both /files/{action} and /api/files/{action}. I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Files",
    url: "api/Files/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Files", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but it not working. I deleted WebApiConfig, so in App_Start is only MVC RouteConfig, but it doesnt help.

**Upd**
controller code

```
public class FilesController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

request urls:
/files/index -> OK (200)
/api/files/index -> Not Found (404)

**Upd #2**
Complete RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FilesRoute",
            url: "Files/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Files", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Files",
            url: "api/Files/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Files", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to add a new route in front of your original route setting.

This setting will first check URL whether is match `Files/{action}/{id}` , if not the use `api/Files/{action}/{id}`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FilesRoute",
    url: "Files/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Files", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Files",
    url: "api/Files/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Files", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**EDIT**

The problem is route setting order you need to set the default route to be the last one.

`/api/files/index` => Otherwise, the setting will find `api` controller and `files` action.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FilesRoute",
            url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Files",
            url: "api/Home/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your request URL and could you post your controller and action code?

Comment: Are you sure you add thoes setting for `RouteCollection` in config class? Because it work if I create a sample project.

Comment: @rsdk I saw your edit your question I modify my answer it should be work